# How to merge MANY lines within same layer that meet (join at some point)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a line dataset. The dataset is vast and the lines are single features in the data layer. I would like to merge the lines which join at some point. How can I do this using ArcGIS 10.1?

For example:
This is the layer, where line fragments are individual records:
[image]

Where separate lines meet other separate lines, I would like to join these to form 1 single line record:
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to explain (perhaps with a picture) what you mean by merging lines, please? Do you mean create intersections?

Comment: PolyGeo,
I have added some pictures, hope that helps explain it better. And no I do not mean intersect,

Comment: I think you are trying to merge contiguous lines into single records.  http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=986&t=249570

Comment: Note that if you use the buffer method described at that question, it appears from your screenshots you will have to use a *very* small buffer to ensure you only get segments that actually touch as opposed to just having endpoints extremely close together. In your lower image, there is a tiny segment at the bottom with a nearly invisible gap and a just barely visible gap in the upper right.

Comment: I can't seem to get that methodology to work polyGeo